# Ruby: How to multiply several numbers?

Tags: ruby, math

I am trying to multiply any number of unknown arguments together to make a total.

```
 def multiply(*num)
  num.each { |i| puts num * num}
  end

multiply(2,3,4)
multiply(2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

**Another attempt:**

```
def multiply(num)
  num.to_i
   i = 0
   while i < num.length
   total = num * num

    return total
   end
end

multiply(2,3,4)
multiply(2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

I keep running into errors: 
(eval):73: undefined local variable or method `num_' for main:Object (NameError)
    from (eval):81

Some saying that Array needs to be Integer.

I've tried doing something I thought was suppose to be very simple program to write.

Comment: `nums.inject(:*)` ie `[1,2,3].inject(:*) #=> 6`

Comment: Does this inject conver the arguments into an array?

Comment: What arguments? `inject` is a method on the `Enumerable` module which you can use on the Array object itself.

Comment: Please take a look at the parameters I am passing...For example in multiply(2,3,4)  I am not passing an array.

Comment: Nevermind, I converted the arguments into an array then used your inject method. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`def multiply(*num)` captures all arguments given to the method in an array. If you run `multiply(1, 2, 3, 4)` then `num` will equal `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. So in both your attempts you're trying to multiply a whole array with itself (`num * num`), which is not going to work.

Others have suggested solutions to how to write the multiply method correctly, but let me give you a correct version of your first attempt and explain it properly:

```
def multiply(*numbers)
  result = 1
  numbers.each { |n| result = result * n }
  result
end
```

As in your attempt I capture all arguments in an array, I call mine `numbers`. Then I declare a variable that will hold the result of all the multiplications. Giving it the value of `1` is convenient because it will not affect the multiplications, but I could also have shifted off the first value off of the `numbers` array, and there are other solutions.

Then I iterate over all the numbers with `each`, and for each number I multiply it with the current result and store this as the new result (I could have written this shorter with `result *= n`).

Finally I return the result (the last value of a method is what will be returned by the method).

There are shorter ways of doing the same thing, others have suggested using `numbers.reduce { |n, result| n * result }`, or even `numbers.reduce(:*)`, but even though they are shorter, they are pretty cryptic and I assume they don't really help you get things working.

Comment: `numbers.reduce(1, :*)` may be preferred as it will return `1` instead  of `nil` if numbers is an empty array (no arguments passed).

Comment: I would actually prefer to return `nil` when there are no numbers, there is no product if there are no numbers (but I realize my proposed solution returns 1 without input -- but I was trying not to complicate things too much).

Comment: I don't have a strong preference, depends on the intended use case; mostly just putting the option out there for the OP `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the #inject method

```
def multiple(*nums)
  nums.inject(:*)
end
```

Inject will combine all of the elements in nums, using the operation specified ( * in this case ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
num.reduce(1) {|x, y| x*y }
```